# A global Enum for comparison operators

Tags: vba, excel, enum

This approach was born out of wanting to pass a logical expression (E.G. ">=10000") as a parameter to a function.

So, I built an Enum and a function to use it to evaluate logical expressions.

Is this a good, maintainable, scalable approach?

```
Public Enum comparisonOperator
    '/ Used [[ ]] because the outer set escape the inner brackets for the Enum list, which will then escape the operator when chosen as a value. E.G. they will appear as "Operator = [<]" in code.
    [[<]] = 1
    [[<=]] = 2
    [[=]] = 3
    [[>=]] = 4
    [[>]] = 5
End Enum

Public Function ComparisonIsTrue(ByVal sourceValue As Variant, ByVal operator As comparisonOperator, ByVal comparisonValue As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim isTrue As Boolean

    Select Case operator

        Case Is = 1 '/ <
        isTrue = (sourceValue < comparisonValue)

        Case Is = 2 '/ <=
        isTrue = (sourceValue <= comparisonValue)

        Case Is = 3 '/ =
        isTrue = (sourceValue = comparisonValue)

        Case Is = 4 '/ >=
        isTrue = (sourceValue >= comparisonValue)

        Case Is = 5 '/ >
        isTrue = (sourceValue > comparisonValue)

        Case Else
        '/ Error Handling
        Stop

    End Select

    ComparisonIsTrue = isTrue

End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> Public Enum comparisonOperator
>     '/ Used [[ ]] because the outer set escape the inner brackets for the Enum list, which will then escape the operator when chosen as a value. E.G. they will appear as "Operator = [<]" in code.
>     [[<]] = 1
>     [[<=]] = 2
>     [[=]] = 3
>     [[>=]] = 4
>     [[>]] = 5
> End Enum
> ```

Why not just *name* them and comply with the language's rules for user identifiers? Also, `Enum` constants should be *enum*erated: let the compiler assign the underlying values:

```
Public Enum ComparisonOperator
    EqualTo = 0
    LessThan 
    LessThanOrEqualTo 
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo 
    GreaterThan 
End Enum
```

There should be a sensible default (`0`) value; I think I'd make `EqualTo` that default.

---

The operators in `Case Is = ...` are redundant, but the magic numbers in the `Case` expressions should be the enum named constants. The underlying values should be abstracted away behind the enum - the underlying values should be meaningless.

Consider:

```
    Case ComparisonOperator.LessThan
    isTrue = sourceValue < comparisonValue

    Case ComparisonOperator.LessThanOrEqualTo
    isTrue = sourceValue <= comparisonValue

    Case ComparisonOperator.EqualTo
    isTrue = sourceValue = comparisonValue

    Case ComparisonOperator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo
    isTrue = sourceValue >= comparisonValue

    Case ComparisonOperator.GreaterThan
    isTrue = sourceValue > comparisonValue
```

That way nothing breaks if the enum members are reordered.