# If ComparisonIsTrue(thisPost, ComparisonOperator.NotEqualTo, goodCode) Then Me.Answer

Tags: vba, excel, math-expression-eval

This is a follow-on to [a global enum for comparison operators](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117856/a-global-enum-for-comparison-operators). I wanted to pass a logical expression E.G. `>= someValue` as a parameter to a function, so I made an Enum and an accompanying function to analyse logical expressions.

---

Is my approach a good way to implement this functionality in VBA?

---

```
Public Enum ComparisonOperator
    NotEqualTo = 0
    LessThan = 1
    LessThanOrEqualTo = 2
    EqualTo = 3
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = 4
    GreaterThan = 5
End Enum
```

---

```
Public Function ComparisonIsTrue(ByVal sourceValue As Variant, ByVal operator As ComparisonOperator, ByVal comparisonValue As Variant) As Boolean

    If IsNull(sourceValue) Or IsNull(comparisonValue) Then GoTo CleanFail
    If IsObject(sourceValue) Or IsObject(comparisonValue) Then GoTo CleanFail

    Dim isTrue As Boolean

    Select Case operator

        Case NotEqualTo
        isTrue = (sourceValue <> comparisonValue)

        Case LessThan
        isTrue = (sourceValue < comparisonValue)

        Case LessThanOrEqualTo
        isTrue = (sourceValue <= comparisonValue)

        Case EqualTo
        isTrue = (sourceValue = comparisonValue)

        Case GreaterThanOrEqualTo
        isTrue = (sourceValue >= comparisonValue)

        Case GreaterThan
        isTrue = (sourceValue > comparisonValue)

        Case Else
        '/ Error Handling
        Stop

    End Select

CleanExit:
    ComparisonIsTrue = isTrue
    Exit Function

CleanFail:
    isTrue = False
    GoTo CleanExit

End Function
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Invalid input**

Consider the following example (**Example 1**): You have a cell A1 containing the value `3`. Now assume the following call:

```
result = ComparisonIsTrue(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), EqualTo, 3)   

' result is now False
```

I made an error and accidentally passed a Range object instead of the value. Now, your method *hides* that error and just returns the wrong result. Instead, I would suggest that you throw an error *with a helpful error message* if an invalid value is passed. That way, you *help* the developer find his error instead of *hindering* him by returning an arbitrary result:

```
If IsObject(sourceValue) Or IsObject(comparisonValue) Then 
    Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "sourceValue and comparisonValue must be value types."
End If
```

As an alternative, there is a "trick" you can use for cases like the one above: VBA has a feature called [Let coersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177257.aspx). Let's consider a modified version of the example again (**Example 2**):

```
Dim x As Variant
x = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

result = ComparisonIsTrue(x, EqualTo, 3)   

' result is now True
```

Since `x` is assigned without the `Set` keyword, the `Range` object is converted to its "simple data value". You can use the same trick inside your method to implicitly convert objects to their data representation:

```
Public Function ComparisonIsTrue(ByVal sourceValue As Variant, ByVal operator As ComparisonOperator, ByVal comparisonValue As Variant) As Boolean

    ' Convert objects to their "simple data value", if necessary.
    sourceValue = sourceValue
    comparisonValue = comparisonValue
```

That way, even Example 1 would return the "expected" result `True`.

**Indentation**

Select-Case statements should be indented as follows:

```
Select Case expression
    Case case1
        Do something
    Case case2
        Do something else
...
```

Answer (score 7):

I really don't like your `GoTo`s...

```
If IsNull(sourceValue) Or IsNull(comparisonValue)
Or IsObject(sourceValue) Or IsObject(comparisonValue) Then
    ComparisonIsTrue = False
    Exit Function
End If
```

And gone are your gotos.

Comment: You are right hat, In *general*, `GoTo` should be avoided. However, in languages like VBA which don't have `finally` blocks, `GoTo` is a legitimate (and, in fact, the only DRY) way to jump to the "clean up and exit" block.

Answer (score 2):

A more "standard" approach would be a `Predicate`. Since my VBA is gruesome here's a C-Style implementation

```
class Predicate<T> {
    ComparisonOperator operator;
    T checkValue;

    boolean test(T value) {
       // your switch goes here
    }
}
```

This allows you to encapsulate and pass a single object instead of two for testing.

Your title would look something like this in the end:

```
Dim codeReviewCheck As Predicate
codeReviewCheck.Operator = ComparisonOperator.NotEqualTo
codeReviewCheck.TestValue = GoodCode

If codeReviewCheck.Test(thisPost) Then
    Me.Answer
End If
```

This is also closer to your original intent:

> I wanted to pass a logical expression E.G. `>= someValue` as a parameter to a function, [..]

Currently you have to pass two parameters. That's not simplistic and leads to parameter bloat on your methods. Encapsulate things that belong together into one single class

Comment: Great idea, but you need function pointers & generics to make that work properly. VBA has neither.

Comment: since the original is working on a Variant anyways, the Generics are actually optional. It's just the C-Style implementation that benefits from these