# Logical Predicate Class

Tags: vba

For a while now I've been playing around with various ways of passing a logical predicate E.G. `>= someValue` as an argument to a function. (see: [If ComparisonIsTrue(thisPost, ComparisonOperator.NotEqualTo, goodCode) Then Me.Answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122582/if-comparisonistruethispost-comparisonoperator-notequalto-goodcode-then-me-a) and [a global enum for comparison operators](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117856/a-global-enum-for-comparison-operators))

In the end, I've decided to build a `CLS_Comparison_Predicate` class with `Operator` and `RightValue` properties, with a `Compare()` function that takes a `LeftValue` as an argument.

Thoughts?

---

Example Usage:

```
Dim predicate As CLS_Comparison_Predicate
Set predicate = New CLS_Comparison_Predicate

predicate.Operator = GreaterThan
predicate.RightValue = 9000

If predicate.Compare(inputValue) Then
    MsgBox "It's over 9,000!"
End If
```

---

Enum:

```
Public Enum ComparisonOperator
    NotEqualTo = 0
    LessThan = 1
    LessThanOrEqualTo = 2
    EqualTo = 3
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = 4
    GreaterThan = 5
End Enum
```

---

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private pOperator As ComparisonOperator
Private pRightValue As Variant

Private Const NULL_ERROR_TEXT As String = "Invalid Compare input. Cannot compare against Null"
Private Const OBJECT_ERROR_TEXT As String = "Invalid compare input. Input must be a value, not an object"

Public Property Let Operator(ByVal inputOperator As ComparisonOperator)
    pOperator = inputOperator
End Property

Public Property Let RightValue(ByVal inputValue As Variant)
    If IsNull(inputValue) Then
        PrintErrorMessage NULL_ERROR_TEXT
        Stop
    ElseIf IsObject(inputValue) Then
        PrintErrorMessage OBJECT_ERROR_TEXT
        Stop
    End If

    pRightValue = inputValue
End Property

Public Function Compare(ByVal leftValue As Variant) As Boolean

    If IsNull(leftValue) Then
        PrintErrorMessage NULL_ERROR_TEXT
        Stop
    ElseIf IsObject(leftValue) Then
        PrintErrorMessage OBJECT_ERROR_TEXT
        Stop
    End If

    Dim isTrue As Boolean
    Select Case pOperator
        Case NotEqualTo
            isTrue = (leftValue <> pRightValue)

        Case LessThan
            isTrue = (leftValue < pRightValue)

        Case LessThanOrEqualTo
            isTrue = (leftValue <= pRightValue)

        Case EqualTo
            isTrue = (leftValue = pRightValue)

        Case GreaterThanOrEqualTo
            isTrue = (leftValue >= pRightValue)

        Case GreaterThan
            isTrue = (leftValue > pRightValue)

        Case Else
            '/ TODO: Error Handling
            Stop
    End Select

    Compare = isTrue

End Function
```

Comment: I might change the names of the two `inputValue` arguments to specify right and left, just looking at the code.

Comment: @Raystafarian wouldn't those conflict with the `Right` and `Left` functions in the `VBA.Strings` module?

Comment: Thoroughly tempted to stir in a little `IComparable` interface in there and support object types (those that implement the interface anyway).

Comment: @Mat'sMug I meant changing them to specify right and left, not be named right and left - like `rightInputValue`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Stop
```

This instruction is outright dangerous in any production code (assuming that code could be used in anything that ends up in the hands of users that don't understand what's happening when the VBE pops up). And because it's easy to forget about it and remove every instance of it everywhere, I usually reserve it for debugging only - for example:

```
CleanFail:
    Stop
    Resume CleanExit
    Resume
End Sub
```

When debugging, execution breaks at the `Stop` keyword, and then I can drag the yellow "next instruction" arrow to `Resume` and jump back at the error-causing line.

If you're going to be outputting an error message and stop execution, you might as well *raise an error* to do so. Runtime error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument" is more or less analoguous to .NET's `ArgumentException`, which seems to be the most accurate existing error to throw/raise here - I'd do it like this:

```
Err.Raise 5, TypeName(Me), NULL_ERROR_TEXT
```

That will only `PrintErrorMessage` if the caller handles the runtime error though, which changes the way your code works. But it's more semantically correct I find.

Same here:

```
    Case Else
        '/ TODO: Error Handling
        Stop
```

The function received an *invalid argument*; there's an existing runtime error *specifically* for this: just use it!

---

> ```
> Public Enum ComparisonOperator
>     NotEqualTo = 0
>     LessThan = 1
>     LessThanOrEqualTo = 2
>     EqualTo = 3
>     GreaterThanOrEqualTo = 4
>     GreaterThan = 5
> End Enum
> ```

Every single enum value here has the same value is would have if an explicit value wasn't specified, and the values themselves are meaningless. Better leave 'em out and only specify explicit values when these values *mean something* or can be *combined* (and then they would be valued with powers of 2).

---

Objects are indeed not comparable. But not because they're objects - because in and by themselves, they don't specify *how* they should be compared. The .NET framework solved this problem by introducing a fairly simple interface, `IComparable`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CompareTo(ByVal other As Variant) As Integer
End Function
```

Given an object that implements this interface, your code would be able to evaluate all operators, assuming both operands are of the same type; so instead of systematically refusing to compare objects, you could instead raise an error that says something like "Both objects must be the same type and implement IComparable".

---

```
Private pOperator As ComparisonOperator
Private pRightValue As Variant
```

I've seen `p` used to mean "parameter". Not sure what it stands for here, as typically the Hungarian prefix would be `m_` for module-scope variables.

I like to solve this problem like this:

```
Private Type TComparer
    Operator As ComparisonOperator
    RightValue As Variant
End Type
Private this As TComparer
```

And then you don't need prefixes anymore:

```
Public Property Let Operator(ByVal value As ComparisonOperator)
    this.Operator = value
End Property
```

Notice I'm using a general-purpose `value` parameter in property setters (let/set); this makes properties read consistently, and pretty much identical to modern VB.

```
Public Property Let RightValue(ByVal value As Variant)
    If IsNull(value) Then
        PrintErrorMessage NULL_ERROR_TEXT
        Stop
    ElseIf IsObject(value) Then
        PrintErrorMessage OBJECT_ERROR_TEXT
        Stop
    End If

    this.RightValue = value
End Property
```

Are you sure `IsNull` is doing what you're using it for here?

> The **Null** value indicates that the **Variant** contains no valid data. **Null** is not the same as **Empty**, which indicates that a variable has not yet been initialized. It is also not the same as a zero-length string (""), which is sometimes referred to as a null string.
>
> <sub>https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278616.aspx</sub>

It's actually pretty hard to supply a `Null` value *by accident* to a required `Variant` parameter. I'm not saying the check isn't needed, just that it's rather uncommon in VBA code. I'm not even sure how one would manage to actually pass a `null` in there *without explicitly specifying `Null`*.

It's good that you're checking for `Null`. But then, why stop there? Why not check for `vbEmpty`? If one can pass `Null`, they could also pass `vbEmpty`... and how would you compare against `vbEmpty`?

Comment: I did not realise (though now it seems obvious) that you can declare an Enum with specifying the numbers.

Comment: You've also just reminded me, I've got an `IsEmptyNothingOrNull` function lying around somewhere ^^

Comment: Would you need to `Option Base` for an `Enum` to start at 1? Or could you assign it like above in the question starting at 1 without it giving a null 0?